# Several alerts in SwiftUI view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

The View has two `.alert` modifiers defined. With different content and different switch bindings.
No matter what the only second is working properly.

For sure I can define more elaborated logic involving the alert ViewBuilder and this is how I made it work right now.

The question is - **Is it expected behaviour? Is there another/better way of doing this?**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var shouldDisplayFirstAlert = false
    @State var shouldDisplaySecondAlert = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: { shouldDisplayFirstAlert.toggle() }, label: { Text("Display First") })
            Button(action: { shouldDisplaySecondAlert.toggle() }, label: { Text("Display Second") })
        }
        .padding()
        .alert(isPresented: $shouldDisplayFirstAlert, content: firstAlertBuilder)
        .alert(isPresented: $shouldDisplaySecondAlert, content: secondAlertBuilder)
    }

    func firstAlertBuilder() -> Alert {
        Alert(title: Text("First"), dismissButton: .cancel({ shouldDisplayFirstAlert.toggle() }))
    }

    func secondAlertBuilder() -> Alert {
        Alert(title: Text("Second"), dismissButton: .cancel({ shouldDisplaySecondAlert.toggle() }))
    }
}
```

So, the possible way to workaround the issue could be like code below. It enable me to have different alerts by elaborating `AlertModel` and `alertBuilder`:

```
struct AlertModel {
    var text: String
    var action: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var shouldDisplayAlert = false
    @State var actionTaken = "none"
    @State var alertModel: AlertModel?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                alertModel = AlertModel(text: "First", action: "First Action")
                shouldDisplayAlert.toggle()}, label: { Text("Display First") })
            Button(action: {
                alertModel = AlertModel(text: "Second", action: "Second Action")
                shouldDisplayAlert.toggle()}, label: { Text("Display second") })
            Text(actionTaken)
        }
        .padding()
        .alert(isPresented: $shouldDisplayAlert, content: alertBuilder)
    }

    func alertBuilder() -> Alert {
        Alert(title: Text(alertModel?.text ?? "none"), dismissButton: .cancel({
            actionTaken = alertModel?.action ?? "none"
            shouldDisplayAlert = false
        }))
    }
}
```

Comment: On `dismissButton` you change the same value in both case?

Comment: No, this is just a copy-past mistake. Thank you for pointing. I'll fix it in the post

Comment: Yes, this is the way to go. What you could also do is to have one flag that controls a single alert and within the `ViewBuilder` for that alert you could switch the content depending on how you want to. In that case though you should really use the `@ViewBuilder` annotation for the method and generally make sure that timing issues don't prevent the content being built the way you want to.

Comment: just have one alert